# Is there a sect-neutral tashahhud?

Tags: salat, tashahhud

Re-reading the answer to my question [Going from "never prayed in my life" to my first prayer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32644/17163), I encounter the importance of [tashahhud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tashahhud).  I'm embarrassed to admit it, but I haven't been doing tashahhud.  After five months, I think it's no longer reasonable for me to use the excuse "...but I'm a new Muslim".

While other aspects of my prayer seem fine (comparable to the other women at mosque), there's two obstacles:

1. I'm brand new to Arabic.
2. I don't belong to a sect ("...just a Muslim"), and I don't intend to (as per [Qur'an 6:159](https://quran.com/6:159); and I perceive them mostly as an obstruction to submitting to Allah).

The Wikipedia page lists five different ones according to various sects [(a) Hanafi and Hanbali, (b) Maliki, (c) Shafii, (d) Ja'fari, and (e) Zaidi]. Basically, I want to avoid choosing one over the others.  The attitude expressed in the question [Is there any problem praying in the same way as Muslims from other sects?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10677/17163) also gives me the impression I should avoid "choosing a side".

If I were to put my mind to it, I could memorize the Arabic (I can recite [al Fatihah](https://quran.com/1) after all; and it seems I need to recite it in each rakaa, so at least 2+4+4+3+4=17 times per day, so I'd get used to it quickly).  However, it seems different sects recite different tashahhud (though fairly similar in content) and I'm reluctant to single out one.

**Question**: Is there a sect-neutral tashahhud?

For example, could I just say the [shahada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada) instead?  Or is there a version that the Prophet Muhammad is known to say?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with a sect neutral tashahud? I'd like to add that you might find on sunnah.com hadith translations with transliteration which may help with the pronounciation maybe i've even linked one before. But i don't think that the Arabic words are necessary for you in this stage.

Comment: Here a few links with transliteration of the words of tashahud: http://sunnah.com/urn/1282500, http://sunnah.com/urn/1282490, http://sunnah.com/urn/1282480, http://sunnah.com/urn/1282470 from sunan ibn Majah

Comment: This fatwa deals with all the known tashahud (sunni) versions https://islamqa.info/en/98031 a newer fatwa says shortly that if the common parts are quoted the tashahud is valid https://islamqa.info/ar/262502 sorry I wanted to post an mp3 link of tashahuds but forgot about as i wanted to check the hardcopy of the audiobook first (and I haven't done it so far).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if I couldn't understand your question correctly - You are asking that if there is anything which doesn't belong to any sect but only to Islam without any sect right?

If you want to find answers to your problems you just need to follow Quran and Sahih Hadith even if the person who is telling you belong to any other sect but should be a person. You need to check which answer has back of Sahih Hadiths and Quran.

Here is the proper Dua of Tashahud I have highlighted the arabic words which should be recited in Tashahud according to the this Hadith - Hadith is Sahih as it belongs to Bukhari

[image]

(reference: [sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/21/6))

Edit: You can hear the pronunciation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a14_LhsFH0A)
Or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFPWiQLqneg).

Screenshot from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0KqEHbIlqo):

[image]

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I just updated the answer check the edits and let me know if you still need help

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0KqEHbIlqo

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones you can see the same videos here http://playit.pk/watch?v=g0KqEHbIlqo