# Do I need to take shahada again

Tags: conversion, shahada

Hi a few years ago I took shahada. When u said it I was only sincere about the part 'there is no god but allah' but when I spoke the part about the messenger I wasn't fully sincere as I didn't feel totally convinced. My mum came with me but she wasn't happy with what I was doing so the whole thing felt uncomfortable and at the time I didn't know much about Islam I'd never even opened a Quran and in the end I stopped praying and went back to my old ways I kept saying I'm a Muslim but didn't fully feel like one. I'm now questioning whether I actually converted since only part of it was said sincerely. I'm now taking my time to learn about Islam but the question of whether I really converted keeps nagging at me

Answer (score 4):

> لا إله إلا الله محمد رسول الله

Regardless of whether or not your prior shahada was accepted, if you want to be a Muslim, then say the shahada.

It's normal for Muslims to say the shahada multiple times per day, e.g., when performing wudu ([Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1254690)) or when saying the [tashahhud](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36133/is-there-a-sect-neutral-tashahhud) during prayer.

Whether or not Allah accepted your initial shahada (and you "need" to say it again) is between you and Allah.

(Oh... and welcome to Islam.)

Comment: And can a Muslim also recite Shahada every night? Will a Muslim be rewarded if he/she recited shahada every night? Just to know.

Comment: I would expect so, based on "So whoever does an atom's weight of good will see it" ([Qur'an 99:7](https://quran.com/99/7)).